# Regularity of FEM a priori

Tags: regularity-theory-of-pdes, finite-element-method, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I am studying the book [Finite Element Analysis](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Finite_Element_Analysis/05gvEAAAQBAJ?hl=en) by Szabó and Babuska, and specifically, section 1.5.1 on regularity defines
$$
u_{EX} = x^{\alpha} \phi (x), \ \alpha > 1/2, \ x \in I = (0, \ell). \tag{1}\label{eqn1}
$$
The authors states

> For $u_{EX}$ to be in the energy space, its first derivative must be square integrable on $I$. Therefore
> $$
> \int_0^\ell x^{2(\alpha-1)} dx > 0 \tag{2}\label{eqn2}
> $$
> from which it follows that $\alpha$ must be greater than $1/2$.

My questions:

1. Might be trivial but how does condition \eqref{eqn2} follow from integrating $u'_{EX}= x^{\alpha-1} [\alpha \phi(x) + x \phi'(x)]$?
2. How does equation $\eqref{eqn1}$ relate to polynomial interpolating functions mostly used in practice?
3. More generally, how is $\alpha$, the convergence rate connected to the index of the sobolev space on which solutions live?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What is or to which space belongs $\phi(x)$ in (1)?

Comment: $\phi$ is an analytic or piecewise analytic function